# AWS Amplify @belongsTo with @auth causes failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am currently experiencing an issue with @belongsTo in connection with @auth when more than one sortKey is inside of the parent element.

The following error comes up when I try to amplify push the schema:

Invalid @belongsTo on Comments:todo. Provided fields do not match the size of primary key(s) for Todos

Below schema should reproduce the error:

```
type Todos @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID!
  createdAt: String
  number: Int
  title: String
  description: String
  comments: [Comments] @hasMany(indexName: "byComments", fields: ["id"])
  baseType: String
    @index(
      name: "byNumber"
      queryField: "todosByNumber"
      sortKeyFields: ["number"]
    )
    @index(
      name: "byTitle"
      queryField: "todosByTitle"
      sortKeyFields: ["title"]
    )
    @index(
      name: "byDescription"
      queryField: "todosByDescription"
      sortKeyFields: ["description"]
    )
}

type Comments @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID!
  todosID: ID! @index(name: "byComments")
  todo: Todos @belongsTo(fields: ["todosID"])
  createdAt: String
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  messageID: ID @index(name: "commentsByMessages")
  message: Messages @belongsTo(fields: "messageID")
}

type Messages @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  content: String
  comments: [Comments] @hasMany(indexName: "byComments", fields: ["id"])
}
```

Does anyone have a solution on how to setup @belongsTo and @auth correctly?

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this? I have no idea what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@belongsTo` and follow this code as an example:

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
}

type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
}
```

Read more about setting up `hasMany` [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship)

Test your code with AWS AppSync before building front-end solutions.